# how to stop redirection in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

when i upload any things (media, post etc). then Wordpress panel redirect to the side of domain name with custom link and show the 404 error page.

```
https://domainname/@custom/
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is not being caused by a plugin conflict.

Deactivate all activated plugins and try the action again. If it gets posted without redirecting you, a plugin might be the cause.

If this is the case, reactivate the recently active plugins and go through the process again, but this time, deactivate the plugins one after the other while you post new items. When you find the culprit, you can uninstall them and replace them with another plugin that does the same job.

If a plugin isn't causing this, you can rename your current .htaccess file to something else, then create an empty .htaccess file on the server. After doing this, go ahead and reset the permalinks.

See if the above suggestions solve your issue. Let e know how it goes.